# CRUD operations by managing foreign key dependencies with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I've two tables, **Organization** and **OrganizationReferent** (that has a column as **foreign key**) as follows:

[image: DB schema]

By using **Hibernate** as *ORM* (in a **JPA**-compliant project), I've obtained entities ad shown **[here](https://gist.github.com/vdenotaris/38077fdeee2e5683cd62)**.
I should manage CRUD operations by using **Java EE 6**-based **Data Access Objects** (**DAOs**).

Both `OrganizationDAO` and `OrganizationReferentDAO` extends a `GenericDAO` Implementation that provides a **create** method as follows:

```
@Override
public EntityClass create(EntityClass entity) throws IllegalStateException, PersistenceException, ConstraintViolationException
{
    entityManager.persist(entity);
    entityManager.flush();
    return entity;
}
```

Now, I defined a `Wrapper` class with the aim to manage **CRUD operations** that involve the two defined tables:

```
@Inject private OrganizationDAO organizationDAO;
@Inject private OrganizationReferentDAO organizationReferentDAO;

public final Organization createOrganization(final Organization organization) throws AlreadyExistsException, BadRequestException, DALException {
  assert(organization != null);
  organizationDAO.create(organization);
}, 

public final OrganizationReferent createOrganizationReferent(final Long organizationId, final OrganizationReferent organizationReferent) throws ConstraintViolationException, AlreadyExistsException, BadRequestException, DALException {
  assert(organizationId != null);
  assert(organizationReferent != null);
  try {
    organizationReferent.setOrganization(organizationDAO.findById(organizationId));
    organizationReferentDAO.create(organizationReferent);
  } catch (NotFoundException e) {
    throw new ConstraintViolationException();
  }
}
```

1. Is this approach right or should I use something different?
2. For the given cardinalities, should I force creations or edit the schema (for instance, changing from `(1,*)` to `(0,*)`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ad 1)

In my opinion your approach is right. One important thing is how you manage your transactions.
One common pattern is to have service-layer classes that have injected many DAOs and methods in such service class is marked as `@Transactional` but DAO methods are never marked `@Transactional`.

Such service class perform complex operations on different objects - that is why it can operate on different DAOs.
Your Wrapper class looks like such service-layer class.

Second thing is using entityManager.flush() is **not recommended** in such place. Forcing flush after each entityManger.persist() break performace if there are more complicated tasks.
You should skip your flush() call - flush() will be automatically called **just before** transaction commit.

ad 2)

I suggest to force creating 1 child record to fit (1,*) requirement...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you also suggest me how to force a create?

Comment: I think of forcing this on your model level. I mean Organisation object has public constructor with OrganizationReferent object. No-arg constructor may be private as long as we use hibernate.